Is it posible to combine depth of field in different scenes
Is it possible to have different Depth of Field settings in different scenes and then combine them? Similar to how you mix lighting in scenes? I tried it quickly but found that the camera renders the same Depth of Field despite different settings in the scenes. Does anyone know how to do this?

either add more cameras with different DOF or keyframe your DOF values.

Sorry, I didn't mention that it's an animation.

Do you mean having multiple focal points in one render ? For example an object at 1m is on-focus, another at 10m on-focus, and everything else is out of focus ? Or do you want to achieve a split diopter lens ? The "combine them" is unclear to me.

Just as you wrote in your first sentence, that's what I mean!

Is that possible?

You could use the Z pass to drive a bokeh blur node, with a colorramp to define the blur according to the distance. I can't write a full answer RN but it should work.

wow! Could you elaborate? I would be so happy!
